# WCF Restful Web Service returning JSON

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, rest

I have been reading up on WCF and was looking for a good tutorial on creating a WCF Restful service that returns Json. I cant seem to find any that are really worth reading, does any have any ones they would recommend for someone who just wants to start with the basics and learn about WCF Restful service? I am unsure if I should start with WCF 3.5 or WCF 4 too. I am using Visual Studio 2010, so I could potentially do either one or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF4 already has nice built-in templates for JSON, whereas in WCF 3.5 it's a bit fiddly and you need to manually add support for that.

[check this out for some docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I honestly used the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169.aspx) and thought it was very thourough.  Its what I used to get up to snuff and build my WCF Rest Service but I am assuming you already looked there.  This was my favorite [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) that I to this day, still have bookmarked.

Pertaining to your 4.0 vs 3.5.  I almost always defer to later technology if you can, especially WCF simply because Microsoft has made things a little easier with things such as what Leon stated.

Answer (score 1):

there are these videos for beginners and certainly very helpful.

you can learn about how to create services within minutes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

There is a video to show how to configure a rest json service as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been reading up on WCF and was looking for a good tutorial on
>   creating a WCF Restful service that returns Json. I cant seem to find
>   any that are really worth reading, does any have any ones they would
>   recommend for someone who just wants to start with the basics and
>   learn about WCF Restful service?

I had exactly the same problem last year.

Eventually, I worked out the steps you have to follow to create a JSON WCF Web Service - it is straightforward *if* you get each of the steps right, but finding an easy-to-follow walkthrough was tough.

Here's the walkthrough I created, clearly documenting what you need to do:

http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm

I follow this walkthrough whenever I create services, both for my ASP.Net apps or iOS apps.

[image: JSON data]

Good luck !